# Android animate layout changes caused by visibility change of children

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to animate visibility changes that leads to height change of a view.

```
<CardView android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/firstView"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/secondView"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</CardView>
```

```
fun updateVisibility() {
   // changing visibility results in height change of the card
   // How do i animate this change?
   if (something) {
      binding.firstView.visibility = View.Visible
      binding.secondView.visibility = View.Gone
   } else {
      binding.secondView.visibility = View.Visible
      binding.firstView.visibility = View.Gone
   }
}
```

I have tried using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the card as well as the children, but that does not result in any animations.

How do i animate the changes?

Comment: Kindly check the windows animation in developers option. If it is off then switch it on.

Answer (score 1):

`animateLayoutChanges` should work set for `CardView` in XML, as this is an attribute of `ViewGroup` and `CardView` extends `FrameLayout`... have you tried to call `enableTransitionType(type)` by code? maybe using `<include` tag somehow disables these transitions (afaik set on by default with `animateLayoutChanges="true"`, but probably before inflating childs)

```
((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.cardView)).getLayoutTransition()
      .enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```